# tkinter python create child window

Tags: python, function, tkinter

Hi I am trying to create a tool that browses a time machine image with Tkinter in python. I plan on using the code from here: http://code.google.com/p/python-ttk/source/browse/trunk/pyttk-samples/dirbrowser.py?r=21 for the directory browser. I have written a start menu and upon clicking on the 'browse' button I want the directory browser to open where the user can select a file and the path is then passed back to the Label (I need to add this as its not in the directory browser code yet). Below is the code for my start menu:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from Tkinter import *
import ttk

class App:

    def __init__(self,master):

        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.label = Label(frame, text="Please enter file path or browse to a file")
        self.label.pack(side=TOP)

        self.button = Button(frame, text="OK", command=messageWindow)
        self.button.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        self.hi_there = Button(frame, text="Browse")
        self.hi_there.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        self.entry = Entry(frame, width = 30)
        self.entry.pack(side=LEFT)

root = Tk()

app = App(root)

root.mainloop()
```

I have read that you cannot have two root frames at once with Tkinter but I am struggling to find an alternative as the directory browser also has a root frame. I am not sure if what I am doing is correct but on the button for browse I have added:

```
 self.hi_there = Button(frame, text="Browse", command=dir)
```

I have put the directory browser code inside of a class and called it dir. So my thinking is that I should be calling the entire class? But then I get an error stating that the name dir is not defined. What ways can I go about getting this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you mean by "a time machine image", but I've got a few things that might help you: don't use the variable name `dir`, as that's a builtin keyword and you're bound to run into problems. If you're having trouble finding the method called `dir` which is inside a class, make sure you're telling it to look inside the class.

```
    def sayHello():
        print "Hello!"


    class Person:

        def sayHello():
            print "Hello from Person"

    a_person = Person()

    sayHello() 
    ##"Hello"

    a_person.sayHello()
    ## "Hello from Person"
```

Calling `printHello` and `class_instance.printHello` are two different functions, and you'll want to pass `class_instance.dir` to the button.

I'm sure you know about them, but there are premade [file dialogs](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog) to help with getting filepaths, filenames etc.

Another thing is you don't want a new `root` instance, you're looking for a new [`TopLevel` instance](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm), which is essentially the same thing as a new `root`, but not quite.

Comment: A time machine image most likely refers to the backup produced from running "Time Machine" on a mac.

Comment: @sc0tt Thanks, I'll have to check that out. Not familiar with macs.

Comment: thank you tankor, I'm having a new problem. Once the button is clicked it is invoking the function but then it stops on the first line which is top = Toplevel.tk(). The error message I receive is: File "test.py", line 95, in directory_browser
    top = Toplevel.tk()
AttributeError: class Toplevel has no attribute 'tk. Any idea?

Comment: @bigl I can't say for sure without seeing the entire code, but it looks like you're trying to call `.tk()` on a `TopLevel` which doesn't have the `tk` attribute. When you want to create a new `TopLevel` just call it like `top = TopLevel()` instead.

Comment: Happy to help. Don't forget to accept the answer if it works for you.